# Accurate way to calculate convolution integrals in arbitrary grids

Tags: convolution, fast-fourier-transform

The convolution integral is defined by:
\begin{eqnarray}
(f*g)(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx f(x)g(y-x).
\end{eqnarray}
Moreover, assume both $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x),g(x)=0$. Now, suppose we have our functions $f,g$ discretized on a set of $N$ points $\{x_{i}\}_{i=0,...,N-1}$, so we have $f_{i}\equiv f[x_{i}]$. Suppose the set $\{x_{i}\}$ ranges values of $\mathbb{R}$ from scales $x_{\text{max}}~ 10^{5}$ to $x_{min}\sim 10^{-5}$, and that we want to compute $(f*g)[y_{i}]$, with $y_{i}\equiv x_{i}$. How can we perform such operation in an efficient way? A FastFourier Transform  method is only of use if the distance between points $\Delta x_{i}=x_{i+1}-x_{i}>0$ is constant; but if the points $\{x_{i}\}$ are unevenly spaced, the method can't be applied. How to compute the integral in that case?

**My approach**: I have mapped the real axis to the interval $[-1,1]$ by using:
\begin{eqnarray}
u =\tanh(x/s),
\end{eqnarray}
where $s$ is a scale factor. Then, I use linear interpolation to calculate the points on a dense set in $u$, and convolve the functions using FFT. To retrieve the result, I interpolate back to $x$ with the inverse mapping. The problem is, the method is not giving satisfactory results. I would like to know how this can be overcomed.

Comment: In general, the map used to get the data into $[-1,1]$ is linear so the distribution of the sample is preserved. This map will depend on the set of data but is easy to compute on the fly. The integral can be approximated by a Riemann sum. If the convolution product is expected to be smooth, a polynomial regression could to the trick. As a summary, the answer to your question is highly context dependent and convolution should rather be evaluated directly here instead of using a change to frequency domain.

Comment: I am ideally looking for a mapping that zooms into the region $|x|<a$, say, where most of the change in the $f,g$ functions takes place. A Riemman integral is of course the straightforward approach, but one runs into problems if the number of points $N$ is too big, as there are $N^{3}$ operations to be performed. A FFT as the advantage that one can reduce the complexity to O(Nlog N), but it only works if the points are equally spaced...

Comment: As stated in my previous comment, the achievable computationnal efficiency (in terms of time but also accuracy) is highly dependent on the context and your data. I am afraid there is no general and efficient answer to your question. For example we could imagine a linear interpolation to transform into an equi-spaced sample distribution so the FFT can be used.

Comment: How would such mapping take place? I mean, how could I transform to an equi-spaced sample so that most information of the $|x|<a$ is retained to compute the convolution reliably? The non-linear mapping $u=\tanh(x/s)$ does not seem to help with this, the solution differs drastically from that of the uniformly-spaced samples on an overly-dense grid.